# jquery/json - create dynamic array for key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I didn't find out, how to create a json message in jquery with dynamic values for a key array element.

I'm trying to build a json message like this:

```json
{
    "line": {
        "name": "Test",
        "images": [
            {
                "order": "1",
                "link": "https://google.com/1.jpg",
                "name": "1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "order": "2",
                "link": "https://google.com/2.jpg",
                "name": "2.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I fail to attach the pictures to the message.

```js
jsonObbj = {};
line = {};
line ["name"] = $("#name").val();
    
counter = 1;
$("div.carousel_image > img").each(function() {
    image = {};
    image ["order"] = counter;
    image ["name"] = $(this).attr('src');
    line ["images"].push(image); // How can I edit this image to the images array
    counter++;
});

// how can I add the line to the array
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `line.images` to an empty array.

```
jsonObbj = {};
line = {};
line ["name"] = $("#name").val();
line["images"] = []; // add this line

counter = 1;
$("div.carousel_image > img").each(function() {
    image = {};
    image ["order"] = counter;
    image ["name"] = $(this).attr('src');
    line ["images"].push(image); // How can I edit this image to the images array
    counter++;
});
```

Note, in general, when your object keys are normal strings, you want to use dot notation: `line.images`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/to4xhewu/

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise `line.images` as an array before you can start pushing to it. You should also  make sure you declare your variables properly with `const`, `let` or `var` or else they will be implicitly *global*.

Try this for a simple, [*object literal initialiser*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) alternative

```js
const jsonObbj = {
  line: {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    images: $("div.carousel_image > img").map((i, img) => ({
      order: i + 1,
      name: img.getAttribute("src"),
      link: img.src
    })).get()
  }
}
```

See https://api.jquery.com/map/